# How can I lock Html table header row and first column by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to lock Html table header row and first column , 
like this example
Click [here](http://www.disconova.com/open_source/files/freezepanes.htm)!

but I have two problem 
1.I want to the right scrollbar and bottom scrollbar on the most top,don't cover
2. When I zoom in or zoom out , the columns be moves .....

please help me , thanks everyone!

Comment: Still wondering, how your code looks like

Comment: http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

Answer (score 0):

For the header row section and first column add css code:

```
position: fixed;
```

It is that simple really. I am not sure what you meant with the zoom in and zoom out.